# Why we always have to use a first element of the collection in hit-testing, not last?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Why we must use `hitTestResult.first` although we can tap several times on a screen and each next our tap is written to an array as a `hitTestResult.last` ?

```
@objc func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPosition: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: sceneView)
    let hitTestResult: [ARHitTestResult] = sceneView.hitTest(touchPosition, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

        if !hitTestResult.isEmpty {

            guard let hitResult = hitTestResult.first else {
                return
            }
            addGrass(hitTestResult: hitResult)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But each tap is treated as a separate event with unique position that you use as location in your scene view. You can then get all the items (I assume) whose projection on screen contain the point given by the point detected from a single event, not several touches. So I assume previous events do not effect current one. If anything I would expect result to be returned sorted by point Z value which means "first" is the closest and "last" is the one that is most at the back.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds interesting. Can you give me a link to documentation?

Comment: The link to het test https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview suggest that it returns all objects as I stated. There is no hint about ordering though. Also no reason to suspect that previous events would anyhow effect the outcome current call.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. Here is the link that even says about the ordering https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest "A list of results, sorted from nearest to farthest (in distance from the camera)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapping several times does not affect the outcome of `hitTest` at all. If user taps 100 times on the same place with 1 object you will still only get 1 object from `hitTest` method.

As from documentation found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest) the objects that will be returned are "sorted from nearest to farthest (in distance from the camera)".

So to try understanding things a bit more basically you may at any given time have any number of objects on your screen. And at any time you may use `hitTest` that will give you all the objects that are at the time visible on the part of the view you define by giving `touchPosition`. As there may be multiple items in same view-location those items are retrieved in array which is sorted so that the items that appear closer to you are at the beginning of the array.

So changing `first` to `last` would only mean to rather use object at the back than the object in front.